# Retrieve Data faster from a huge Oracle Table

Tags: oracle, index

I have a huge Oracle table ( ttdinv700 ) which contains almost 20 million rows.

I am trying to execute the below query, on the table:

```
   select max(ttdinv700.t$trdt) 
   from ttdinv700, ttiitm001
   where ttdinv700.t$item = rpad(ttiitm001.t$item,16,' ')
   and ttdinv700.t$koor = 1
   and ttdinv700.t$kost in (2,7);
```

The execution is taking a lot of time. Could you please suggest a way to retrieve the data faster?

I cannot partition the table as this is a production database.

Comment: Please show the execution plan, all defined indexes and the table structure. And I don't understand why you couldn't introduce partitioning into a production database. That's where partitioning makes the most sense. Btw: what is a "*crore record*"?

Comment: Is the `rpad()` really necessary?  Why would the join key have different formats in different tables?

Comment: yup.. rpad kills. might a function based index help any chance?? both has to be varchar2 anyways.

Comment: yes . The  ' t$item ' column in both the tables  ttdinv700  and  ttiitm001  is  described as  char(16)  , And not Varchar2 . Thats why RPAD  was  used

Comment: @user3254725 if tht column is indexed, any function call over it in the sql makes oracle not to use that index. So try creating a function based index in your test regions

Comment: If `t$item` is char(16) in both tables, I don't think you need the `rpad`. If you remove the `rpad` it might be able to take advantage of indexes on one or both of those columns. Also, the magic values (`1`, `2`, `7`) look suspicious - are they really like that in your code, or do you use bind variables?

Comment: How many rows in `ttdinv700` have `t$koor = 1`? How many rows in `ttdinv700` have `t$kost in (2,7)`? How many rows in `ttdinv700` have `t$item = rpad(ttiitm001.t$item,16,' ')`? And, most importantly, how many rows satisfy all 3 conditions?

Comment: Do you really want to join `ttdinv700` to *all*  rows of `ttiitm001`?

Comment: Which indexes do you currently have?

Comment: the table ttdinv700 has 20 million rows  where as the table ttiitm001 has 3 Lakh rows .  ttdinv700  is  much larger table compared to the table ttiitm001.

Comment: For some of the t$item  in table  ttiitm001 , the lengths vary like 12 , 14 and 16.  So to make it length 16 , they have added spaces  by RPAD , and then they have compared the values with the t$item  in  table  ttdinv700

Answer (score 1):

When I recall correctly this is a query on BaaN version 4 or so probably. The official BaaN policy is that the Oracle drivers require ALL text fields to be VARCHAR which has some different semantics than VARCHAR2. I guess that your `rpad` was introduced by someone to compensate for that but it should not be there.

Also, you should try to avoid adding indexes etc yourself. The BaaN middleware takes care of that and although it is possible to add indexes things can go wrong during upgrades etc.

I don't have a BaaN system on Oracle present at this moment, but I think you are missing some leading columns of the index in your query, something like company/warehouse since you seem to be determing possibly the last inventory transaction per logistic item. Oracle version 9 and higher sometimes can compensate for that.

My advice is to press F4 in TOAD or Invantive Query Tool on ttdinv700 and check the columns listed in the index. Add missing entries to the where clause. Or check contents of `user_ind_columns`.

Then do the same for ttditm700 (the items). The rpad effectively disables index use but depending on your statistics it should be the driving table for the query (most companies have relatively few items compared to their stocks). Try to enable the index on ttditm700.

IMHO this question belongs on stackoverflow and not here.